# Not able to assign Pardot Admin

Tags: pardot

I am at the initial stage of setting up a Pardot Dev Sandbox. During the very first step to assign an Admin User and create a Business Unit I am just getting a blank screen and getting no option to add any assignments

[image]

I am using System Admin profile Marketing User is checked and have got all the necessary permissions. Still not able to proceed.

Can someone please help me in this

Comment: Does this help you(https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322209&type=1)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this was being performed in the sandbox and the licences were not in sync with Production